# How to save data locally in Realm?

Tags: realm

I'm making an app in Swift that will have a Realm database with some preset data in it when the user downloads it from the app store. I know how to make database entries  when it's based on user interaction, but I can't figure out the best way to just have the data already there as soon as it's downloaded.

Any advice on this issue will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bundle a pre-built Realm file with you application that you copy over to the default realm path if there's no file already at that path.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still really new to this and don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean having a file that's just a giant write transaction? Like beginWriteTransaction ... RLMArray.addObject... commitWriteTransaction?

Comment: No, you can create a .realm file in development that you ship with your application.